# Correct column label in conditional dplyr group_by

Tags: r, dplyr

I can use a conditional statement within a dplyr group_by to change which fields I am grouping by based on another variable. Here is a simple example with `starwars`:

```
library(dplyr)

my_val <- "Droid"
starwars %>%
  group_by(if(my_val == "Human") {eye_color}
            else if (my_val == "Droid") {homeworld}) %>%
  summarize(mass = sum(mass))
```

However the column name that resuls is the string of the conditional statement:`if (my_val == "Human") {\n    eye_color\n} else if (my_val == "Droid") {\n    homeworld\n}`

I could put a column name in before the condition:

```
group_by(Character_Type = if(my_val == "Human") {eye_color}
                          else if (my_val == "Droid") {homeworld}) %>%
```

But I want the column name to match the column that is selected in the conditional statement, either `eye_color` or `homeworld` in this example.

How can I set the column name to just be the same as the field that gets selected in the conditional statement? I could pull the conditional statement outside of the dplyr statements, but it will be simpler to leave it inside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

```
library(dplyr)
 my_val <- "Droid"
 starwars %>%
   group_by(!!rlang::sym(ifelse(my_val == "Human","eye_color","homeworld"))) %>%
   summarize(mass = sum(mass))
# A tibble: 49 x 2
   homeworld       mass
   <chr>          <dbl>
 1 Alderaan          NA
 2 Aleen Minor       15
 3 Bespin            79
 4 Bestine IV       110
 5 Cato Neimoidia    90
 6 Cerea             82
 7 Champala          NA
 8 Chandrila         NA
 9 Concord Dawn      79
10 Corellia         157
# ... with 39 more rows
```

or

```
starwars %>%
  group_by(!!rlang::sym(case_when(my_val=="Droid"~"homeworld",
                                  my_val=="Human"~"eye_color"))) %>%
  summarize(mass = sum(mass))
```

Comment: Thanks jyjek. It seems that requires me to switch to `ifelse()` and I actually have more than two conditions to test in my actual scenario. Is there a way to keep the existing conditional format?

Comment: you can use `case_when` for multiconditional

Answer (score 0):

We could use the `group_by_at` which can take string as input

```
library(dplyr)
starwars %>% 
  group_by_at(if_else(my_val == "Human", "eye_color", "homeworld")) %>% 
  summarise(mass = sum(mass))
# A tibble: 49 x 2
#   homeworld       mass
#   <chr>          <dbl>
# 1 Alderaan          NA
# 2 Aleen Minor       15
# 3 Bespin            79
# 4 Bestine IV       110
# 5 Cato Neimoidia    90
# 6 Cerea             82
# 7 Champala          NA
# 8 Chandrila         NA
# 9 Concord Dawn      79
#10 Corellia         157
# ... with 39 more rows
```